# Remove validation highlighting on dependend field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate two fields. Validation should be ok if any field filled(and failed if both fields empty)

I added following validators:

```
   //The adapter
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
            'eparncr', [], function(options) {
                options.rules['eparncr'] = {};
                options.messages['eparncr'] = 'Error message';
            }
        );

        //The validation method
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("eparncr", function (value, element, params) {

            if ($('#val').val() == '' && $('#val2').val() == '') {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
```

and HTML code:

```
<input id="val" type="text" name="val" data-val="true" data-val-eparncr="" />   
<input id="val2" type="text" name="val2" data-val="true" data-val-eparncr=""  />
```

But after validation when i fill one of the fields other still highlighted as error field.

Example:

[image]

Left field filled but right has red color. 
Why this happens?

Comment: It's happening because only the active field is evaluated.  You'll have to re-trigger validation on the whole form to get all fields to be re-evaluated whenever something changes.  There are several methods.  Calling `.valid()` on the form will force another validation test.

Comment: @Sparky what do you think where is better place to call valid for whole form?